# Posibility of filter rows on list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

It is possible to not display specific (eg. not having `original_id` column) rows on list in rails_admin.

Environment: RoR 5.1.2, rails_admin 1.2.0

Comment: is this what you are finding?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179848/in-rails-admin-how-can-i-filter-based-on-the-presence-of-an-association-id

Comment: no, i want filter when page is rendered (not that filter when user filter ;) ) https://i.imgur.com/OgY3A4s.png This marked row have not null field `original_id` and i want to not display that in default

Comment: okay, i figured out myself :) for the future reference --> https://pastebin.com/raw/TDTpjsvA

Comment: Congratulations